# Pick random winners from .csv

Tags: python

I'm totally new to python. Just trying to find out how to pick few, but not the same (unique by ID) winners from the .csv file. Anyone could help?

```
def generate():
    global filename, totalEntries, timestamp, winnerName, winnerID, winnerEmail
    filename = enterFile()

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timestamp = now.strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p")

    with open(filename, newline="") as entriesCSV:
        entriesDict = csv.reader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")

        totalEntries = len(list(entriesDict)) - 1 # ignore our header row

    winningNumber = random.randint(1,totalEntries)

    with open(filename, newline="") as entriesCSV:
        entriesDict = csv.DictReader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")

        for row in entriesDict:
            if int(row["#"]) == winningNumber:
                winnerName = row["Name"]
                winnerID = row["ID"]
                winnerEmail = row["Email"]
                print(f"The winner is {winnerName}, ID {winnerID}, email {winnerEmail}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. I've removed the globals as you didn't really seem to have been using them, then the code generates 5 unique random integers and then for each of them prints out your winner rows. Note that this works if the row "#" is a record number. If you want to alter the number of winners just change the variable at the top.

```
def generate():
    filename = enterFile()

    noOfWinners = 5
    winningNumbers = []
    while len(winningNumbers) < noOfWinners:
        luckyNumber = random.randint(1, totalEntries - 1)
        if luckyNumber not in winningNumbers:
            winningNumbers.append(luckyNumber)

    with open(filename, newline="") as entriesCSV:
        entriesDict = csv.DictReader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")

        for number in winningNumbers:
            for row in entriesDict:
                if int(row["#"]) == number:
                    winnerName = row["Name"]
                    winnerID = row["ID"]
                    winnerEmail = row["Email"]
                    print(f"The winner is {winnerName}, ID {winnerID}, email {winnerEmail}")
```